# RFC 2616 HTTP Content-Length and Transfer-Encoding Compatibility

Tags: http, go

[RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) states that the `Content-Length` header must not be sent if a `Transfer-Encoding` is present.

> The Content-Length header field MUST NOT be sent if these two lengths are different (i.e., if a Transfer-Encoding header field is present).

However, if both headers are received, the client should ignore the `Content-Length`

> If a message is received with both a Transfer-Encoding header field and a Content-Length header field, the latter MUST be ignored.

Is my interpretation correct that the client should treat the case where both headers are present as a proper HTTP response? Or is this clause implementation specific?

I'm asking because the Go standard `net/http` package returns an error when such scenario happens.

Comment: RFC 2616 is obsolete -- check RFC 7230. Not sure if it is gonna help, but it might

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard does not really specify what should happen in this case, only that if the message is accepted at all then the `Content-length` should be ignored. To cite from [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3):

> If a message is received with both a Transfer-Encoding and a
> Content-Length header field, the **Transfer-Encoding overrides the
> Content-Length**.  Such a message might indicate an attempt to
> perform request smuggling (Section 9.5) or response splitting
> (Section 9.4) and **ought to be handled as an error**.

Note the weak *"ought to"* here which is far from MUST. But at least `net/http` is fully correct in that this kind of response is wrong and **can be handled as error**. But it is **not required to be treated as error**.

In practice all browsers seem to accept such a response and usually ignore the `Content-length` header. But I've seen als a behavior with MS Edge in the past where it correctly treated the response body as chunked but additionally used `Content-length` and ignored any bytes from the response body not covered by the `Content-length`.

Comment: Thank you! This helps so much. TIL RFC 7230